# .DLL/.SO library wrapper for Python

Tags: python

I heard of [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html), but the examples given don't really match my needs because they all involve `gcc`.

I have a dynamic library `foo.dll` along with the corresponding header `foo.h`.

In my library I may have:

```
// foo.h
typedef int HANDLER;

int init(HANDLER* dh);
int cry(HANDLER dh, int intensity);
int smile(HANDLER dh, int intensity);
int die(HANDLER dh);
```

I would like to wrap this library in python package that could be used like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import foo

him = Foo()
him.cry(20)
him.smile(10)
him.die()
```

Behind my wrapper I am expecting something like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = cdll.LoadLibrary("foo.dll")
        self.handler = p_int()
        self.foo.init(pointer(self.handler))

    def cry(self):
        return self.foo.cry(self.handler)
```

What is the proper tool to do this automatically?

Comment: there is no proper way to do it automatically, usually there are that much special cases. Also, you are loading the dll for each use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say [Cython](http://cython.org/), and as an example (?) the first search for "cython dll" gives:
http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~krussell/html-tutorial/wrap_dll.html